# Enviar uma requisição POST com java

Tags: java, json, post

Preciso enviar uma requisição POST para o seguinte endereço que é uma API da Amazon:

> https://ikd29r1hsl.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod/contaazul/grade

E nessa requisição tem que ser enviado um JSON:

```
{
    "token": "633cc5hs58512b012104c7408d60d19930d5514",
    "email": "exemplo@hotmail.com",
    "answer": [
        {"date": "2017-09-01", "value": 100},
        {"date": "2017-09-02", "value": 200},
        {"date": "2017-09-03", "value": 150}
    ]
}
```

Alguém poderia dar uma luz sobre como eu faço isso com Java? Exite uma classe que faz esse tipo de operação?

Answer (score 2):

Vou citar três formas:

- A nativa do Java, usando HttpURLConnection (bem baixo nível, não recomendo);
- Usando a biblioteca [Apache HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html). [Aqui tem um exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19912858/2241463) de requisição POST com JSON;
- Usando a biblioteca [OkHttp da Square](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) (era minha maneira favorita de fazer em 2015, não sei se a Apache melhorou de lá para cá, compensa comparar as duas. [OkHttp tem exemplo em português para Android (e Java?)](http://blog.alura.com.br/facilitando-as-requisicoes-utilizando-okhttp-no-android/)).

Comment: Retrofit funciona perfeitamente em projetos Java, e eu acho muito eficiente - https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-send-objects-in-request-body

Comment: É verdade, tem o Retrofit também, só lembrando que ele é voltado para Web Services REST (provavelmente é o caso da Amazon), enquanto que as formas citadas são mais genéricas.

Comment: Na vdd o Retrofit é uma implementação da Okhttp, que faz vc economizar muito tempo na criação de requisiçoes, pois vc evita muita fadiga de código

Comment: [A Retrofit é uma API desenvolvida pela Square seguindo padrão REST...](https://www.devmedia.com.br/android-retrofit-primeiros-passos-com-a-retrofit-api/31857) / [Retrofit is a REST Client for Android and Java by Square...](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html) / [Retrofit is a type-safe REST client for Android (or just Java) developed by Square...](https://guides.codepath.com/android/consuming-apis-with-retrofit) E o que falou é contraditório. Se Retrofit faz a mesma coisa que OkHttp, pq uma roda em cima da outra? Pq a Square criaria duas bibliotecas que fazem a mesma coisa?

Comment: Retrofit é uma implementação da OkHttp assim como o ServeFace e uma implementação JSP, tanto é que a inicialização da Retrofit vc tem opção de inserir um client OkHttp

Comment: A questão que Retrofit ajuda vc a tratar as entidades diretamente na requisição ao invez de tratrar os bytes de resposta e fazer um controle para converter

Comment: ...desde que sua API web seja REST. E não diga implementação; Retrofit não é uma especificação que OkHttp implementa e nem vice-versa. OkHttp é usado como _networking layer_ do Retrofit, ou seja, Retrofit usa o OkHttp. Quando você propôs o Retrofit deu a entender que ele era um facilitador de requisições HTTP. Mas o OkHttp já é isso, e eu falei que eles não compartilham a mesma utilidade pois têm objetivos diferentes. OkHttp simplifica requisições HTTP. Retrofit trabalha um nível acima, mapeando chamadas REST (e não qualquer chamada HTTP) para objetos.